# Error Data Model while Refresh Pivot Table

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I got this error while try to refresh a Pivot Table in my Excel workbook. The data is from the same workbook.

I try to make another Pivot Table but the error still there...

How can I fix this?

[image: img]

Comment: I've heard some changes are a "one-way street". Have there been any changes to either the pivotTable or the data model since it was last refreshed? If so, that may be the cause. Unfortunately, I don't know any other fix besides starting over.......

Comment: @Mistella you mean i need to make the data model back?

Comment: I don't know if it's un-doable or not but this is example #42873 of why it's a good idea to turn on [automatic backups](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/automatic-backups-excel) for files you wouldn't want to lose tomorrow.

Comment: Does the user have file restore set up?

Comment: @Fahmieyz **If** there were changes to either the pivot tables or the query directly prior to this, then most likely. If there were no changes, I don't know what might be the cause or the fix.....